# Адаптив для блока с элементами

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Мне нужно сделать адаптив к данному блоку, чтобы не ломалось.
https://codepen.io/Glebmak/pen/JjjQEgo

- Проблема с отступами, т.к. я указал, что у каждого 4-го элемента
  будет отступ справа, можно конечно же при адаптиве все подгонять под
  каждый пискель, но это не очень граммотно.
- Проблема с space-between, если на строке 2 элемента, то логично что элементы будут прижаты к правой и левой стороне.

Пробовал разные способы, указывал ширину элемента calc(16.66%) и т.п.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid #1b559e;
}
.fix__time {
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin: 8px 26px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #dde0e3;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 12px 16px 0;
}

.fix__time-btn {
    height: 32px;
    width: 72px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b559e;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fix__time">
    <ul>
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">15:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">16:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn none">—</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn none">—</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">17:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">18:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">19:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">20:30</div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, походу никто не знает как это сделать, что очень странно, либо никто не хотел помочь. 
В итоге решил сделать на гридах и вроде как все четко

```css
.container {
  max-width: 420px;
  border: 1px solid #1b559e;
}
.fix__time {
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin: 8px 26px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #dde0e3;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(84px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 46px;
  grid-gap: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.fix__time-btn {
    height: 32px;
    width: 72px;
    line-height: 32px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b559e;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fix__time">
    <ul>
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">15:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">16:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn none">—</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn none">—</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">17:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">18:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">19:30</div></li> 
      <li><div class="fix__time-btn">20:30</div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```